# Threading caused app to lag on iOS but not on Android

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm building a face detection app in Unity3D for both iOS and Android. The app is supposed to detect 10 faces per second. However, each face detection takes about 50 ms, so I've decided to let the face detection run in the background on another thread in order to prevent small lag spikes (the apps need to update visual stuff every frame, 50 ms stops makes it laggy).

The problem is that threading caused the app to lag on iOS. Without threading it used to detect 10 faces per second, now 2 with threading.. It works fine on Android.

**What's weird** is that the app runs fine on iOS for the first 5 seconds. It doesn't matter if it detects faces or not, after 5 seconds comes heavy lag. EDIT: If I pause the app and then resume it the lag disappears for another 5 seconds like in the start. What is this!?

Down below is a coroutine where the face detection is handled, it runs 10 times per second. If the face detection thread doesn't finish in 100 ms it prevents another thread from starting.

```
    IEnumerator FaceDetection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (faceDetectionThreadDone)
            {
                rgbaMat = webCamTextureToMatHelper.GetMat();
                if (rgbaMat != null)
                {
                    OpenCVForUnityUtils.SetImage(faceLandmarkDetector, rgbaMat);
                    faceDetectionThreadDone = false;

                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                        // heavy computing stuff (50 ms)
                        List<UnityEngine.Rect> detectResult = faceLandmarkDetector.Detect();
                        if (detectResult.Count > 0)
                        {
                            points = faceLandmarkDetector.DetectLandmark(detectResult[0]);

                        }
                        faceDetectionThreadDone = true;
                    }).Start();

                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
```

Is there some serious problem with how I create new threads? I've read somewhere that they get cleaned up by the garbage collector once they're done executing. Might that cause the lag? The build settings are set on high performance etc.

**EDIT:** Ok, I'm pretty sure now that the problem isn't related to memory management. I've run the internal profiler in Xcode and watched how much of the heap was used. The perfomance didn't get affected when the garbage collector kicked in.

Devices that I tested the app on: iPhone 6, Sony Z3, Samsung S4

Comment: Have you checked the build settings for iOS and Android. I think there is multithreading features that one can be enabled.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into that and tried all kinds of build settings. Haven't found any specific ones for multithreading though.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating and starting `Thread` is expensive.  Each time

```
Thread(() =>
{
//Code
}).Start();
```

is called, about 1 MB memory is allocated. Add other memory allocation that happens inside there such as `List`(detectResult) creation.

Also, `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);` allocates memory but I don't think this is the problem. You can prevent this by declaring `WaitForSeconds` before the while loop then using it.

For example,

```
//Create instance of WaitForSeconds once, before the while loop
WaitForSeconds waitForSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

while (true){
//your Thread code
}
yield return waitForSeconds; //No more memory allocation
```

Don't really that that is the main problem but I put that let you know you could do that. For the `Thread` problem I mentioned above, you should create a `while` loop that processes your data then performs the output in the main `Thread`. Basically a Thread function that will loop forever instead of creating a new `Thread` each time.

There is a plugin called [Unity Threading Helper](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-threading-helper.90128/) that allows you to call Unity API functions from another Thread. You may want to use it. It has paid and free version. The free version does not includes examples in it. That's the only difference but you can download it and examples of it on the link I posted.

Below is a general example of how to use that API. Read the comments in the code. Your job is to put the codes in your question into the appropriate location which is easy to do.

```
bool keepProcessing;
UnityThreading.ActionThread myThread;
void Start()
{
    keepProcessing = true;
    //Create Thread once
    myThread = UnityThreadHelper.CreateThread(() =>
    {
        //Will process Data forever!
        while (keepProcessing)
        {
            //Do heavy computing stuff 

            //Computing Done! Do something with the output data
             UnityThreadHelper.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
              {
                   //You can safely call Unity API functions inside this codeblock
              }

            //Wait so that Unity won't Freeze
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    });
}

void stopProcessing()
{
    keepProcessing = false;
    myThread.Abort();
}
```

Finally, I suggest you re-design your `DetectLandmark` function to take in `array` as parameter instead of `List`. Allocate enough array memory once then re-use it. This will completely remove memory allocation from your app.

Comment: Yes, creating only one thread is much better, thanks. It didn't solve my problem, though. The heavy computing stuff in the thread still get slowed down after 5 seconds. The performance really drops, it goes from perfect to horrible in the blink of an eye. I'm starting to think that it isn't a thread related problem, but the fact that the performance didn't drop when I had the heavy computing stuff in the main thread keeps telling me that the problem probably is how the facelandmarkDetector object gets accessed from the second thread when the app has been built for iOS.

Comment: @Johan I really don't know what your `faceLandmarkDetector.Detect()` and `faceLandmarkDetector.DetectLandmark` function looks like but they may  actually be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Application.targetFrameRate to 15 in 1/30 frames and to 60 in 29/30 frames solved it......

Must be a vsync related bug in Unity..